# An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.(HRESULT: 0x8007000B) while whole architecture is 32 Bit

Tags: c#, windows-services, 32bit-64bit, dllimport, loadlibrary

I am facing this issue while DLL Importing a 32 bit C++ DLL in Windows Service which is also 32 bit. I have even tried using LoadLibrary method and the issue remains same. The same source code and dll are working perfectly fine on 64 bit systems! Can anyone please help me in this regard? I have gone through majority of SO posts and posting this query after complete research. Each and every Build configuration has already been matched to 32 bit.

Comment: Probably means that the dll has a reference to another dll and that the one that it finds is a 64-bit version.

Comment: No dependency at all. Just a single DLL containing all the code.

Comment: The error message suggests otherwise. Most likely you have a dependency on the MSVC runtime that you are not aware of.

Comment: Agreed @DavidHeffernan but its a default dependency and its installed in the system with correct architecture i.e. 32 bit.. I have no external or third party dependency for sure.

Comment: OK, so what's your explanation then? You claim to have a 32 bit process and a 32 bit DLL with no dependencies. How can you explain it?  Most likely your beliefs are incorrect.

Comment: What does `GetLastError()` return after *LoadLibrary* failure?